# Build Docker Image for Angular with NPM

Tags: angular, docker

Hi I am trying to build docker image for my angular app here is my docker file

```
#FROM nodejs/base:latest


#Input Parameters
ARG version

#Set environment variables
ENV HOST localhost
ENV PORT 8080
ENV SERVICE_NAME App-Web




WORKDIR /App-Web
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN npm install
COPY . .

ADD src/ /App-Web/
EXPOSE $PORT

#Run mimeo ui
#CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
CMD bash -c "cd /App-Web/ && \
ls -lt && \
npm start && \
tail -f app.log
```

here is my angular-cli

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"],
            "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
```

the package.json is this

```
{
    "name": "App-ui",
    "version": "4.0.0",
    "license": "Apache",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js --host 0.0.0.0 -p 8080 --disable-host-check >> app.log 2>&1 &",
        "buildProd": "ng build --prod",
        "buildDev": "ng build",
        "gitbuild": "ng build --prod --base /argus_ui/master/dist/",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
```

I have defined 2 properties in package.json

**"buildProd": "ng build --prod",
        "buildDev": "ng build --dev",**

and when I try to do `npm run buildDev` its still taking the prod properties

Comment: build ng app in docker? this will add the difficulty to debug. what about build your app out of docker, and just add the build output of the project to docker?

Comment: It will be helpful, if you can provide the output which shows that by running `npm run buildDev`, it is still taking prod properties. Also, your `buildDev` variable has `"buildDev": "ng build"` and not `"buildDev": "ng build --dev"`